# mysql is not running after restarting my server

Tags: mysql

I'm using suse linux OS. My database is not running, this happened soon after restarting my database server. when i type `rcmysql` status command it is showing the below error.Please help me.

MySQL is not running

```
failed mysql.service - LSB: start and stop MySQL
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-03-10 08:44:22 UTC; 4 days ago
Process: 16170 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the ownership and permissions of your database directory (usually /var/lib/mysql)